# How do i overlay a button on Webview?

Tags: android, android-layout, button, webview, overlay

I'm a noob to android development i have a framelayout that overlays a two buttons on top of a viewflipper that contains a listview and a multiple webviews.  The buttons display as they should above the listview, but when I filp to the webview the buttons dissappear.  I have tried wrapping each webview in the viewflipper in a framelayout and then adding the the button inside the webview.  when i do this The buttons don't dissapper, but they lose their orientation.  Any help fixing this is greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tab2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/previous"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|left"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text="&lt;"
    android:textSize="48dp" >

</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|right"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text=">"
    android:textSize="48dp" >

</Button>

<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListViewId"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
    </ListView>

    <FrameLayout 

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webViewnews"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/previous"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|left"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="&lt;"
            android:textSize="48dp" >
        </Button>

          <Button
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|right"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text=">"
            android:textSize="48dp" >
          </Button>

    </WebView>
</FrameLayout>       

</ViewFlipper>
```

Comment: RelativeLayout gives the results.  Buttons with no orientation.

Comment: Its not just a matter of just changing FrameLayout to RelativeLayout, you must adapt your Layout, use the Layout Builder in eclipse. Look up also examples. Its easy once you see how it works.

Comment: No luck. i tried the suggestion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793381/webview-and-buttons-layout-makes-buttons-invisible?rq=1